# Create a raw SQL statement ready to be used in PostGIS from a geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql

Given an existing geometry in QGIS 3.28+ (e.g. from a temporary scratch layer), is there a quick way (i.e. with the lowest amount of user actions) to generate the PostGIS geometry definition (raw SQL statement) that would fit into whatever SQL query (ideally using the current map SRID)?

E.g. the geometry that would fit into:

`SELECT 'bar', 'baz', <the_generated_postgis_geometry_object_from_qgis>;`

Comment: If inside the *DB Manager* just `SELECT ST_AsEWKT |ST_AsEWKB(geometry) FROM <scratch_layer> [WHERE ...];` in the layers section, and copypaste the result into the PostGIS query (wrapped in `'` and suffixed with `::GEOMETRY` of course). Or just do your thing in *SpatiaLite SQL*.

Comment: Seems promising, but this is giving: `Query preparation error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): no such function: ST_AsEWKT` in the DB manager when executing the query on the scratch layer. (QGIS 3.34.3)

Comment: Well, best to check the *SpatiaLite* function reference; it has to be `AsEWKT|AsEWKB` (no `ST_`) in its dialect.

Comment: Indeed, but then the command prefix the query with the SRID, which I guess is not suitable for directly inserting into a PostGIS query: `SRID=4326;POLYGON((1.434694...`

Comment: Oh on the contrary, EWKT is a PostGIS own extension to WKT; just cast that string to `GEOMETRY` and it get's the SRID set for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a virtual field (type text) that gets the text representation of the geometry and ads the projection. Then you can copy/paste from the attribute table.

```
'st_setSRID(\'' || geom_to_wkt($geometry) || '\'::geometry,' ||   substr( @project_crs,6) || ')'
```

[image]

You can also adapt this into an `action` so you can right click a feature to compute and copy the geometry text.